# Can I extend actor in use case?

Tags: uml, actor, extend, use-case

Can I extend actor in use case?
for example I have "normal user" , "student user" and "teacher user"...
every use case the "normal user" uses it ,by default the "student user" and "teacher user" use it too..
so can I extend "normal user" for "student user" and "teacher user" ? is that popular ?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How!! I ask a question and someone answer me! why @casperOne closed it??? it's bad ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for example, you may have a Database Administrator and an Active Directory administrator.

You can factor out the common needs to a new base actor "System Administrator" for a simplified model.

You can represent the actor generalisation like any other, draw a solid line with a closed arrow pointing from the specialised actor to the base actor.